# Google search callback function

Tags: javascript, google-search, google-search-api

Hello I am new to programming and came across a task abour google search api. I went through the docs and wonder what does the code below will do? below will do.

```
 const myWebSearchStartingCallback = (gname, query) => {
      const hour = new Date().getHours();
      return query + (hour < 12 ? ' morning' : ' afternoon');
    };
    window.myImageSearchStartingCallbackName = myWebSearchStartingCallback;
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#example-search-starting-callback):

> The example search starting callback in [Example Search Starting Callback](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#search-starting) adds either morning or afternoon to the query depending on the time of day.

A callback is a function that gets called at a later point in time, for example when the user of the website takes some action. In this case, the callback gets called when the user enters a search query, and this callback modifies the search query to add either "morning" or "afternoon" to the end of that search depending on the user's current time.